# Insert JSON Fails Node-Postgres

Tags: javascript, postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to insert an array of JSON into Postgres. Everything appears to run successfully (the table gets created), but there is no data inserted, and no error given. I am using the async/await method for transactions, but I can't understand what is failing.

```
(async() => {

    const client = await pool.connect()

    let val= [
        {"table_pk":1,"NAME":"my Great Name","ROLE":"name1"},
        {"table_pk":2,"NAME":"new Name","ROLE":"name1"},
        {"table_pk":3,"NAME":"someone's funny name","ROLE":"name1"}
        ]

    try {
        await client.query('BEGIN');
        await client.query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable')
        await client.query(`CREATE TABLE myTable(table_pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, role TEXT)`)

        await client.query(`INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::myTable, $1::jsonb)`,[JSON.stringify(val)]);
        await client.query('COMMIT');
    }
    catch (e) {
        await client.query('ROLLBACK');
        throw e
    }
    finally {
        client.release();
    }
})().catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

**EDIT** 
Updated the code to account for missing INSERT, now rows will insert, but not all the data.

Comment: And where is your `INSERT`? You are not adding anything into the table.

Comment: Doesn't 'json_populate_recordset' do the insert for you? I guess I was under the impression it would based on the postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: You're misunderstanding. It populates the result of the `SELECT`, it got nothing to do with inserting records.

Comment: You are correct. I was missing the insert. I have updated my code. I have seen another issue with failing to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INSERT failed because JSONB is case sensitive when it comes to column names. I had Upper Case column names in the val data and they should have been lower. Thanks to @vitaly-t for pointing out the missing INSERT in my original post.